# Adobe Air - KeyboardEvent error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

The code below throws the error **1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: KeyboardEvent.**

Does anybody know why?

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.system.System;

if (Capabilities.cpuArchitecture == "ARM")
{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);
}



function handleKeys(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem (as you indicated in your comment to it), please accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the KeyboardEvent class.

Does this work (Note the additional import statement I've added):

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.system.System;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

if (Capabilities.cpuArchitecture == "ARM")
{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);
}



function handleKeys(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
This one was missing: **import flash.ui.Keyboard**